# Is there a way I can change colors of text output in Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node

I am using protractor for my AngularJS E2E testing. I use the DOS command line with a white background and black test.

I have the following set up:

```
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
      isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
      stackTrace: false
  }
```

What happens is that I see the first few lines in black on white:

```
C:\Test\NodejsConsoleApp1\NodejsConsoleApp1>node_modules\.bin\protractor conf.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Homepage1
    Open a page with an id of ng-app
```

Then the text background changes to black and I see black, red and green on a dark background.

Is there a way I can change this?

Comment: is `jasmineNodeOpts` in your `protractor.conf.js` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if there is a better/cleaner way (maybe a config file, i don't know...)

i got interested and searched 'color' in node_modules/protractor and found this in
node_modules/protractor/lib/cli.js starting at line 47

```
    ANSIColors: {
       pass:    function() { return '\033[32m'; }, // Green
       fail:    function() { return '\033[31m'; }, // Red
       neutral: function() { return '\033[0m';  }  // Normal
    }
```

[color code cheat sheet](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html)

anyway, strange behavior of your console to change its background color. windows console has an option to set its appearance and save it (by its console name..? i am on linux now, cant check). not sure if this helps preventing the console from changing its color by it self.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did go in and make some changes. Console still changing colors if I go for non-default font size.  Seems ood but at least things are better than before.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter) to display your results, there is an option to disable colors.